# HTML form not submitting when ID tag is used

Tags: javascript, jquery, post, forms, jquery-validation-engine

I have a working form. However, in order to do some JQuery stuff (*hide and show a div*), I need to add an `id` tag to the form.

When I add the `id`, the jQuery is working as expected, but my page stops Posting.

```
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") // this is working
```

**POST working -**

```html
<form method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER[" PHP_SELF "]);?>">
```

**POST not working -**

```html
<form method="post" id="target" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER[" PHP_SELF "]);?>">
```

Any ideas why this is happening?

**EDIT - JQuery added below. ID is unique.**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  jQuery("#target").validationEngine('attach', {
    onValidationComplete: function(form, status) {
      if (status == true) {

        document.getElementById("content").innerHTML = "its working";
        document.getElementById("content1").innerHTML = "its working1";

        //$(".form-bottom-section").hide();
        // Set the effect type
        var effect = 'slide';

        // Set the options for the effect type chosen
        var options = {
          direction: 'right'
        };

        // Set the duration (default: 400 milliseconds)
        var duration = 700;
        //$('.form-bottom-section').toggle(effect, options, duration);
        $('.order-bottom-section').toggle(effect, options, duration);
      }
    }
  });

});
```

Comment: How are you submitting the form - submit button? jQuery?

Comment: Can you share your jQuery code as well?

Comment: **Just** adding an `id` attribute would not cause the effect you describe. There must be some other factor at play, such as some JavaScript you haven't shown us. You need to create a [MCVE]

Comment: JQuery code added above. ID attribute is unique. Submit button is used.

Answer (score 1):

jQuery-Validation-Engine doc: 
https://github.com/posabsolute/jQuery-Validation-Engine#onvalidationcomplete

> When defined, it stops by default the form from auto-submitting, and
>   lets you handle the validation status via a function. You can also
>   return true in this function and the form will be allowed to submit.

Because you defined this callback, so it will stop submitting.

Add `return true` will solve your problem.

Comment: I have added return true, after '$('.order-bottom-section').toggle(effect, options, duration);'. It is now POST'ing, however my jQuery isn't working. The toggle/hide is being ignored if I return true.

Comment: Please define **isn't working** , is there any error message in console?